# Maven hard-deploy in JBOSS 7

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

Previousally we where using JBOSS 5 and the codehaus plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin) to deploy war to JBOSS. We where using the `jboss:hard-depoly` maven goal. This goal could be executed even if my JBOSS server was not up

Recently we moved to JBOSS 7, and started using the plugin (http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) . we are now using the goal  `jboss-as:deploy` goal. This plugin does not support `hard-deploy` and jboss must be started to run this goal.

Is there a specfic reason to not support the hard-deploy goal?Simply copying the war file to deployements directory in JBOSS 7 still works and why this goal is not included?

Comment: I would suggest to ask JBoss why they removed the goal.

Comment: Surely i will ask JBoss if Stackoveflow also confirms the same. I am not 100% aware about JBOSS 7 changes, hence confirming.

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBASMP-70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jboss-as plugin uses JBoss Management api to do everything it does. If Jboss AS7 is not up, there will of course be no JBoss Management endpoint handling requests. Having such hard-deploy would imply totally different approach - one would have to define JBoss home and parse its configuration offline. Since this is not in general supported by the plugin, I'd imagine that is the reason hard-deploy goal is not supported as well.

Comment: For users who wants a workaround for the same see -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936893/jboss-7-x-redeploy-option