# Jboss 7.x redeploy option

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss7.x, maven-plugin

I was looking for hard-deploy option in Jboss &.x but I believe that option is no longer supported in Jboss 7.x
what I found was  [this Jboss link containing latest plugins](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/)
.

I have decided to use **Jboss-as:redeploy** option.It seems to work perfectly for me- kind of replacement for hard-deploy.But when I check my Jboss/standalone/deployment folder the timestamp of war is not updated.But code changes are reflected in the application.below is the maven plugin code  that I am using

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>redeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>`
```

Is there any bug in jboss plugin there ?Is it the right way to achieve my hard-deploy goal in Jboss 7.x

Comment: I'm curious as why a timestamp change matters. Better put as I'm not familiar with what hard-deploy does, could you possibly explain it?

Comment: well If I am making a new build which generates a new WAR.If it is getting deployed it should be copied to the deployment dierctory of the Jboss.That is what hard-deploy used to do in older Jboss versions

Comment: Ah, I see. The jboss-as-maven-plugin uses the deployment API to deploy the WAR it does not copy the WAR anywhere. The deployment directory is only used if a deployment scanner is turned on. Which it is by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no hard-deploy feature in the jboss 7.We have now used maven plugin to copy the new build to the deployment directory and Jboss will detect the change and deploy the new WAR.Below is the code for the same:

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-war-file</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="target/myapp.war" tofile="${env.JBOSS_HOME}\standalone\deployments\myapp.war" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```